# Getting stack trace in async EF core interceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to get the full stack trace inside an EF core interceptor on method

```
 public override Task<DbDataReader> ReaderExecutedAsync(
            DbCommand command,
            CommandExecutedEventData eventData,
            DbDataReader result,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

`Environment.StackTrace`

`new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()`

Both are only giving the internal EF stack trace

really want the whole stack trace if possible

Comment: No, they should show the entire stack trace, but your own code is probably many stack frames deep.

Comment: You should also be building a DEBUG version.  RELEASE builds will have much less stack information